# Effect of Schottky diode capacitance for LM2596-based buck converter

Tags: buck, schottky

I select a schottky diode to output a DC / DC converter.
Found several SMD SS52 options. One option has a capacity of 800pF, the other 200pF.
The smaller the capacity, the better? The version with 800pF has smaller overall dimensions, which is attractive, but the issue with capacity interferes.

[image]

There is also a reverse voltage issue. There is an option for 20V, there is for 200V. The voltage of the circuit to which the diode will be connected is 5V. Can I choose 200V without harm?

Comment: Diode capacitance varies with reverse voltage. Make sure you're comparing capacitances at the same voltage...

Comment: What does the data sheet for the 1N5824 tell you?

Comment: All the parameters you discuss are of little consequence to the performance of the DCDC converter. I would simply choose the diode that is suggested by the manufacturer but if I wanted a different model I'd select one with a lower forward voltage and/or faster recovery times and/or a package with lower heat resistance.